# ConnectionBackend not working in angular 2 release? How do I provide XHRBackend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

**TypeProvider `ConnectionBackend` is no longer working after upgrading from Angular `2.0.0-rc.5` to `2.0.0`.**

When I put it in my list of providers. I get this error from Visual studio code.

> [ts] Argument of type '{ bootstrap: typeof AppComponent[]; declarations: (typeof LoginComponent | typeof EmailLoginCompo...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
>     Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
>       Type '(any[] | typeof HttpModule | typeof Location | typeof AuthStore | typeof RequestInterceptor | typ...' is not assignable to type '(TypeProvider | ValueProvider | ClassProvider | ExistingProvider | FactoryProvider | any[])[]'.
>         Type 'any[] | typeof HttpModule | typeof Location | typeof AuthStore | typeof RequestInterceptor | type...' is not assignable to type 'TypeProvider | ValueProvider | ClassProvider | ExistingProvider | FactoryProvider | any[]'.
>           Type 'typeof ConnectionBackend' is not assignable to type 'TypeProvider | ValueProvider | ClassProvider | ExistingProvider | FactoryProvider | any[]'.
>             Type 'typeof ConnectionBackend' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>               Property 'push' is missing in type 'typeof ConnectionBackend'.

I have looked at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d5515473bfd0974bacb0e7e5870e772426c9088d/CHANGELOG.md) and I don't see anything that applies here. I did notice that, for example `HTTP_PROVIDERS` had been replaced with `HttpModule`,  but that was in the changelog and the entire reference was missing. This is much stranger.

**What am I meant to use in the release version of angular 2 to provide a XHRBackend?**

---

*This is a sort of appendix, of all the code concerned. The question part has finished already:*

Here is my NGModule. My app runs fine (except for breaking when it needs to provide the Http object) with the `ConnectionBackend` line commented out.

```
    @NgModule({
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        EmailLoginComponent,
        EmailLoginCodeComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        ExampleComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
      ],
      providers: [
        appRoutingProviders,
        HttpModule,
        Location,
        AuthStore,
        RequestInterceptor,
        ResponseInterceptor,
        ConnectionBackend, // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
        {
            provide: Config,
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions],
            useFactory: (
                backend: XHRBackend,
                defaultOptions: RequestOptions
                ) => {
                    let config = new Config(new Http(backend, defaultOptions));
                    // I hope this promise finishes
                    let promise: Promise<Config> = config.load().then( response => config);
                    return config;
                },
        },
        {
            provide: PanelGuidStore,
            useFactory: (
                () =>
                    new PanelGuidStore()
                ),
        },
        Locator,
        {
            provide: AuthService,
            // Factory for AuthService
            // use standard http here to avoid circular references
            //      (as well as pointless attempts to put Auth tokens inside Auth requests)
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthStore, Config, Locator, PanelGuidStore],
            useFactory: (
                backend: XHRBackend,
                defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                authStore: AuthStore,
                config: Config,
                locator: Locator,
                panelGuidStore: PanelGuidStore
                ) =>
                new AuthService(
                    new Http(backend, defaultOptions), authStore, config, locator, panelGuidStore
                ),
        },
        {
            provide: Http,
            // Factory for Http
            // Use custom http provider to inject access tokens and deal with access token expiry
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Location, RequestInterceptor, ResponseInterceptor],
            useFactory: (
                backend: XHRBackend,
                defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                location: Location,
                requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor,
                responseInterceptor: ResponseInterceptor,
                authService: AuthService) =>
                new AuthHttpProvider(
                    backend, defaultOptions, requestInterceptor, responseInterceptor
                    ),
        },
      ],
    })
```

This is what visual studio code has to say about it's "providers" parameters:

> (property) providers: (any[] | typeof HttpModule | typeof Location | typeof AuthStore | typeof RequestInterceptor | typeof ResponseInterceptor | {
>       [x: number]: undefined;
>       provide: typeof Config;
>       deps: (typeof XHRBackend | typeof RequestOptions)[];
>       useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => Config;
>   } | {
>       [x: number]: undefined;
>       provide: typeof PanelGuidStore;
>       useFactory: () => PanelGuidStore;
>   } | typeof Locator | {
>       [x: number]: undefined;
>       provide: typeof AuthService;
>       deps: (typeof XHRBackend | typeof RequestOptions | typeof AuthStore | typeof Config | typeof Locator | typeof PanelGuidStore)[];
>       useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, authStore: AuthStore, config: Config, locator: Locator, panelGuidStore: PanelGuidStore) => AuthService;
>   } | {
>       [x: number]: undefined;
>       provide: typeof Http;
>       deps: (typeof XHRBackend | typeof RequestOptions | typeof Location | typeof RequestInterceptor | typeof ResponseInterceptor)[];
>       useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, location: Location, requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor, responseInterceptor: ResponseInterceptor, authService: AuthService) => AuthHttpProvider;
>   })[]

Comment: `ConnectionBackend` is just an interface. This is the interface that `XHRBackend` implements. We need a `ConnectionBackend`, and `XHRBackend` is the implementation. So you can just take out the `ConnectionBackend` provider.

Comment: Do you get any runtime errors when you take it out?

Comment: @peeskillet yeah. "No provider for XHRBackend". If I try to provide `XHRBackend` directly, I get "No provider for BrowserXhr" which leads down a rabbit hole that I can't find the end of (I think "No provider for ResponseOptions" is next).

Comment: Maybe it's not getting the XHRBackend from the HttpModule. Maybe try taking out the HttpModule, and just check out [its source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/http/src/http_module.ts#L45), and explicitly add the other providers you are missing from the module. To clean it up, just create your own module and import it

Comment: Duhh I think I see the problem. You should be importing the HttpModule ,not adding it as a provider

Comment: @peeskillet. Awesome, thank you so much. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConnectionBackend` is just an interface. This is the interface that `XHRBackend` implements. So you can just take out the `ConnectionBackend` provider.

The reason you are getting the missing `HRBackend` error is because you should be *importing* the `HttpModule`, not adding it as a provider

```
imports: [ HttpModule /* DO */ ],
providers: [ HttpModule /* DONT */ ]
```